# flutter - FCM: custom vibration on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wrote an app that should notify people if something happend. Because of that it is important, that the people hear the notification. i have chosen flutter to develop parallel for android and ios. For android I have now got everything done.

For iOS I have been able to get my own sound on notifications.
But I don't found a solution how I can set my own vibration.
Do either of you know how I can set a vibration other than the short twitch?

I used the tutorial from firebase_messaging on flutter.io and set the sound during the notification rest call on the server.

If you want to see the source code, I can add it.
I thank you in advance for your support.
Kai

Comment: Hey, I am also trying the same, did you manage to add custom vibration for iOS?